# UITextView, cannot disable scrolling

Tags: scroll, uitextview

Using UITextView, I am having the following issue. I am using iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

I first intended to use a simple UITextField, but since I need two lines of text I have gone to UITextView.

Having enough space for the two lines, this is fine. I do not need to have the scroll.
Therefore I did:

```
myTextView.scrollEnabled=NO;
```

But this is where problems start:
I do not have two lines displayed any more, just one (partly invisible). And of course this is not what I want.

How can I keep my two lines and get rid of the scroll?